# jQuery global colour replace

Tags: jquery, colors, replace

I have a large file with several tables in it and I can edit the source. I have several rows like this:

```
<tr bgcolor=#cccccc ><td>some data </td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#ffffff ><td>some data </td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#080808 ><td>some data </td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#cccccc ><td>some data </td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#ffffff ><td>some data </td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#cccccc ><td>some data </td></tr>
<tr bgcolor=#cccccc ><td>some data </td></tr>
```

I need a jquery statement to replace colors. So I may want to say anything with a color of #cccccc change to #09c ( blue ) and anything with a bg color of #ffffff change to #080808 )(black).

I quess it would be something like this but cant get it to work

```
$('*').filter(function() {
var match = 'rgb(182, 211, 252)';
return ( $(this).css('background-color') == match );
}).css('background-color', '#e7e4d3');
```

This works if I use the RGB colors but I need it to work with hex colors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks baz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you rightly, you'll want something like - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sGLAc

```
$('tr').each(function(){

    var row = $(this),
        bg = row.attr('bgcolor');

    switch(bg.toLowerCase())
    {
      case '#ffffff':
        row.attr('bgcolor', 'red');
      break;

      default:
        console.log(bg);
      break;
    }

  });
```

Comment: Perfect chirstian very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `rgbtohex`

**sample**

```
function rgb2hex(rgb)
{
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    return "#" +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

$(function()
{
    $('tr').each(function()
    {
        var mainTr = $(this);
        var trColor = rgb2hex($(this).css('background-color'));

        //check for hex code and replace it accordingly...
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this one helpful for you.

```
$("*").css("color", "red");
$("table tr").each(function(){
    //alert($(this).attr("bgcolor"));
    if($(this).attr("bgcolor") == '#cccccc')
    {
        $(this).attr("bgcolor","#09c");
    }
    if($(this).attr("bgcolor") == '#ffffff')
    {
        $(this).attr("bgcolor","#080808");
    }
});
```